# Two Python classes for a web crawler

Tags: python, object-oriented, http

I am using the Python module `urllib3`. It occurs to me that there is a better way to design a good class when I rebuild my last site crawler.

```
class Global:
    host = 'http://xxx.org/'
    proxy=True
    proxyHost='http://127.0.0.1:8087/'
    opts=AttrDict(
        method='GET',
        headers={'Host':'xxxx.org',
              'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0',
              'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
              'Accept-Language':'en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
              'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
              'Connection':'keep-alive',
              'Cookie':'xxxxxxx',
              'Cache-Control':'max-age=0'
              },
        assert_same_host=False
    )
    def getPool(self,proxy=None):
        if proxy is  None:
            proxy = self.proxy
        if(self.proxy):
            http_pool = urllib3.proxy_from_url(self.proxyHost)
        else:
            http_pool = urllib3.connection_from_url(self.host)
        return http_pool


class Conn:
    def __init__(self, proxy):
        self.proxy= proxy
        self.pool = Global().getPool(self.proxy)
    def swith(self):
        self.pool = Global().getPool(not self.proxy)
    def get(url, opts=Global.opts):
        try:
          self.pool.urlopen(
              method=opts.method, 
              url= url, 
              headers= opts.headers, 
              assert_same_host=opts.assert_same_host
              )
        except TimeoutError, e:
            print()
        except MaxRetryError, e:
            # ..
```

I try to make class contains all global configs and data for others to call, 
just like I do in JavaScript. But, are these classes too tightly coupled? Should I just merge them together?

Comment: I think that those two are really parts of the same class. And should be combined.

Comment: Does anyone need access to this stuff besides `Conn`? If not, it probably belongs in `Conn`. If you're worried about creating a separate copy of all of these constants in every `Conn` instance, you can make them class variables instance of instance variables. (And you may want to make `getPool` a `@classmethod`, too.)

Comment: Actually I just need change configs and grab rules  for  every specifical site, merge the two class together means I should create a lot of different Conns and make code lager.I just wonder is it deserved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Class design

A good class in general is one that corresponds to an *Abstract Data Type*,
which is a collection of data and operations that work on that data.
A good ADT should have a single, clear responsibility.

The `Global` class is not a good ADT:

- It does two unrelated things:

  - Contain configuration information
  - Manage a proxy pool
- Possibly as a consequence of the previous point, it is poorly named

It would be better to split this class into two:

- `Configuration` or `Config`: contain configuration information
- `ProxyPoolManager`: manage a proxy pool

Note that `ProxyPoolManager` should not reference `Configuration` directly:
it will be best to pass to it the `proxyHost` and `proxy` as constructor parameters.

As the poorly named `Conn` class already does half of the proxy pool management,
it would be better to rename it to `ProxyPoolManager` and move `getPool` method into it and rename `Global` to `Configuration`.

#### Coding style

You have several coding style violations, not conforming to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

- Use spaces around `=` in variable assignments, for example:

  - `proxy = True` instead of `proxy=True`
  - `opts = AttrDict(...)` instead of `opts=AttrDict(...)`
- No need to put parentheses in `if(self.proxy):`
- There should be one blank line in front of method definitions of a class: put a blank line in front of `get` and `switch` methods in the `Conn` class
- You mistyped `switch` as `swith`

#### Other issues

This code doesn't compile:

> ```
> class Conn:
>     def get(url, opts=Global.opts):
>         try:
>           self.pool.urlopen(...)
> ```

Because it makes a reference to `self` which was not passed in as method parameter.

---

This is a bit hard to understand,
because of reusing the name "proxy" both as method parameter and as attribute:

> ```
> def getPool(self,proxy=None):
>     if proxy is  None:
>         proxy = self.proxy
>     if(self.proxy):
>         http_pool = urllib3.proxy_from_url(self.proxyHost)
>     else:
>         http_pool = urllib3.connection_from_url(self.host)
>     return http_pool
> ```

The purpose of this method would be more clear if you used a different name for the method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`getPool()` doesn't use the `proxy` argument. The method starts by using the class value to set a default value. However, the if statement just uses the class value and ignores the argument it just assigned a default value to.